# Aggregate over several variables which contain NA values

Tags: r, aggregate

I have the following data frame:

```
x <- read.table(text = "  id1 id2 var1 var2
1   a   x    1    NA
2   a   x    2    4
3   a   y    2    5
4   a   y    4    9
5   b   x    1    7
6   b   y    4    4
7   b   x    3    9
8   b   y    2    8", header = TRUE)
```

which contains one `NA` value in the first row. I use the `aggregate()` function to apply several functions on several variables in one call:

```
aggregate(cbind(var1, var2) ~ id1 + id2, data = x,
          FUN = function(x) c(mn = mean(x), n = length(x)))
```

This leads to the following output:

```
  id1 id2 var1.mn var1.n var2.mn var2.n
1   a   x       2      1       4      1
2   b   x       2      2       8      2
3   a   y       3      2       7      2
4   b   y       3      2       6      2
```

Unfortunately, the complete row which contains an `NA` value in var2 is dropped for **every** variable (**also var1**).

Any solution to use the `aggregate()` function on several variables in one call without losing all rows which contain an `NA` value?

My preferred output should look like this:

```
  id1 id2 var1.mn var1.n var2.mn var2.n
1   a   x     1.5      2       4      1
2   b   x     2.0      2       8      2
3   a   y     3.0      2       7      2
4   b   y     3.0      2       6      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aggregate(x[c("var1", "var2")], x[c("id1", "id2")],
      function(x) c(mn = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), n = sum(!is.na(x))))
#  id1 id2 var1.mn var1.n var2.mn var2.n
#1   a   x     1.5    2.0       4      1
#2   b   x     2.0    2.0       8      2
#3   a   y     3.0    2.0       7      2
#4   b   y     3.0    2.0       6      2
```